# Regex to remove special characters in java

Tags: java, regex

I have a string with a couple of special characters and need to remove only a few (~ and `). I have written the code below, but when I print the splitted strings, getting empty also with values.

```
String str = "ABC123-xyz`~`XYZ 1.7A";

String[] str1= varinaces.split("[\\~`]");

        for(int i=0; i< str1.length ; i++){
            System.out.println("str==="+ parts[i] );
        }
```

Output:

str===ABC123-xyz
str===
str===
str===XYZ 1.7A

why empty strings also printing here ?

Comment: I would have to say that maybe it has something to do with the fact that you have a String variable named **str** which contains a specific string. But instead of splitting **str** you split a String variable named **varinaces** and place all the elements from that split into a String Array named **str1**. Now, with a **for** loop,  you iterate through some unknown Array named **parts** based on the length of the newly created array of **str1**. Geez, this is starting to get confusing. Where in the world did **varinaces** and **parts*** come from?

Answer (score 0):

You’re splitting on *one* special char... split on 1 *or more*:

```
String[] str1= varinaces.split("[~`]+");
```

Note also that the tilda `~` doesn’t need escaping.

Answer (score 0):

Its because when you use the `.split()` method it returns a String array of 4 items shown below:

```
String[4] { "ABC123-xyz", "", "", "XYZ 1.7A" }
```

And then in your `for` loop you printing all items of that array. You can use the following to resolve it:

```
for(int i=0; i< str1.length ; i++){
if(parts[i].compareTo("") > 0) {
    System.out.println("str==="+ parts[i] );
}           
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The split method returns the stuff around every match of the regex. Your regex, `` [~`] ``, matches to a single character that is either "~" or "`". 
The parts of the string separated by matches to that regex are determined as follows:

The string "ABC123-xyz" is returned because it is split off the given string at the character: "`". 
In between that character and the next match, "~", is the empty string, and so on.
If you want it to match to more, use `` [~`]+ ``